# MS access query List

Tags: database, ms-access

I am working on a MS access query optimization because, it is taking long time to run and sometimes it is giving the response and sometimes not. While drill down the entire query I got this line

```
qry List at tbl at AGENT_STAFF Active MAX END DATE
```

Which when I tried to run separately, its not able to run. I need to understand this line and know how to run this.

Comment: What is this supposed to be? Part of the SQL? Because that ain't SQL. What do you mean by "drill down the entire query"?

Comment: @Andre Yes, its part of the SQL inside the Left Join [qry List ASDT tbl ASDT P1T_AGENT_STAFF Active MAX END D]. By Drill Down, I meant to analyze the query.

Comment: If it's `LEFT JOIN [qry List ASDT tbl ASDT P1T_AGENT_STAFF Active MAX END DATE]`, then all inside the [square brackets] is simply a (very convoluted) query name. Otherwise please post the full query.

Comment: @Andre Yes I got it ..Actually very new to Access DB. The query that I am referring is too slow, before it was giving the response but now I don't know what happened, its not at all giving any response. Trying to optimize the same.  Thank you so much for help..Thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts in square brackets, like

```
LEFT JOIN [qry List at tbl at AGENT_STAFF Active MAX END DATE]
```

are object names (tables, queries or field names).

So you'll need to analyze the subquery in the join.

Comment: Needed your help again..I have a left join like `LEFT JOIN [tbl ASDT P1T_AGENT_STAFF]
ON ([qry List ASDT tbl ASDT P1T_AGENT_STAFF Active MAX END DATE].MaxOfSTF_END_EFF_DT = [tbl ASDT P1T_AGENT_STAFF].STF_END_EFF_DT))` The problem is that when ever I try to run my query with this I am not getting the data whereas once I remove, everything seems to be Okay...Would request to guide me how to optimize this?

Comment: The Subqueries contains only the SELECT statements..I searched on Web and got Views are possible in Access..So was thinking if we add indexes on Views, then the query result will be faster but not getting any way to add index in the above query i.e. `qry List ASDT tbl ASDT P1T_AGENT_STAFF Active MAX END DATE`

Comment: @Lara: I have no way of debugging or analyzing this without a detailed description of table structures and relations, and sample data to reproduce any errors. You will have to ask a new question for that.

Comment: @Lara: Indexes can only be added to tables. Again, we would need the table structures to help.

Comment: Okay..As a novice in this DB World , Would request to kindly guide me as how to debug this query on my own?